# Update IMPORTHTML result by copying formula from cell and back using GoogleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, refresh

I want to make a portfolio tracker that takes the info from the web and updates every minute (time trigger) plus - by a button (this part is not very relevant I suppose).

Here is the example Sheet with some example data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ikqv-XtHkEl6VOdPKG9QotnG31o09sZMPdAozzAM4Qs/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried the script to copy from and back into the same cell in one move, but it does not trigger Sheets to refresh the data.

I guess, that if the range is taken from the existing position, moved to another, and (here is where it fails) move back - it must work. It does update when moved once.

I found the script, that works perfectly to one side. But I am not able to make it to the end.

What I've tried:

- making two functions work one after another with reversed ranges;
- making separate sourceRange, targetRange and source2Range, target2Range with the same logic.
- making similar one, but with flush in between them;
- making one function to do all the moves one after another;

None of the above worked pased the point where the range is moved one time.
Here are the code options used:

```
function refreshPortfolioData() {
  var activeSheet,numberOfSourceColumnsToGet,sourceColumnStart,sourceFormulas,sourceRange,
      sourceRowStart,targetColumn,targetRange,targetRowStart;

  //USER INPUT

  sourceRowStart = 6; //Row to start getting formulas from
  sourceColumnStart = 7; //Column to start getting formulas from
  numberOfSourceColumnsToGet = 1; //Number of columns to get formulas from

  targetRowStart = 6; //Row to start copying formulas to
  targetColumn = 21; //Column to start copying formulas to

  //END OF USER INPUT

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sources');
  sourceRange = activeSheet.getRange(sourceRowStart, sourceColumnStart, activeSheet.getLastRow(), numberOfSourceColumnsToGet);

  sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

  targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart,targetColumn,sourceFormulas.length,sourceFormulas[0].length);

  targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
  
  targetFormulas = targetRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range
  
  //SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  sourceRange.setFormulas(targetFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
  }
```

Example of extention to reverse the changes:

```
  <...>
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  var activeSheet,numberOfSourceColumnsToGet,sourceColumnStart,sourceFormulas,sourceRange,
      sourceRowStart,targetColumn,targetRange,targetRowStart;

  //USER INPUT

  sourceRowStart = 6; //Row to start getting formulas from
  sourceColumnStart = 21; //Column to start getting formulas from
  numberOfSourceColumnsToGet = 1; //Number of columns to get formulas from

  targetRowStart = 6; //Row to start copying formulas to
  targetColumn = 7; //Column to start copying formulas to

  //END OF USER INPUT

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sources');
  sourceRange = activeSheet.getRange(sourceRowStart, sourceColumnStart, activeSheet.getLastRow(), numberOfSourceColumnsToGet);

  sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

  targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart,targetColumn,sourceFormulas.length,sourceFormulas[0].length);

  targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
  }
```

Anyone can help me with the options here?

Comment: You could try triggering the function with a clientside setInterval function.  But you may exceed your quota rather quickly.  Keep in mind your quota is calculated as a rate/day rather than a fixed number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In order to refresh the formulas on Google Spreadsheet, it seems that it is required to replace others from the current formulas once. In your script, the same formulas are overwritten. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In your situation, I thought that `sourceFormulas` might be able to be directly put to the `sourceRange` instead of `targetRange` using `clearContent()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart,targetColumn,sourceFormulas.length,sourceFormulas[0].length);

targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range

targetFormulas = targetRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

//SpreadsheetApp.flush()

sourceRange.setFormulas(targetFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
```

To:

```
sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();
sourceRange.clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might not be required to be used.
sourceRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);
```

#### Note:

- As other approach, when TextFinder is used for your situation, it becomes as follows.

  ```
    function sample() {
      var orgFormula = "=TRANSPOSE";
      var tempFormula = "=sample";
      const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sources').getRange("G6:G14");
      range.createTextFinder(orgFormula).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(tempFormula);
      range.createTextFinder(tempFormula).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(orgFormula);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thank you very much! The first option works as expected. 
The second one is totally new to me, so even more helpful!

Comment: @Povi1as Thank you for replying and testing them. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.